# R, tryCatch error

Tags: r, try-catch

I am parsing alot of website and I wrote a script that loops thru the thousands of link from a separate file. However, I experienced that sometimes R couldn't load one link and it stops in the middle of loop, leaving many of other urls unparsed. So I tried to use tryCatch, so the script ignores this case and keep parsing next urls. However, I recently experienced that tryCatch generates below error.

```
gethelp.url = 'http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Vault-General/bd-p/101'
gethelp.df =tryCatch(htmlTreeParse(gethelp.url, useInternalNodes = T), error = function() next) 

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : unused argument (cond)
Calls: withRestarts ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

The confusing thing is sometimes it works well and sometimes it throws out this error message, even though the same script parses the same urls.

Can anyone give me a guidance how to interpret this error messages? I read the document but i couldn't find much insights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your function has to have `cond` as an argument – at least that's how I've used `tryCatch()` in the past, and your error message seems to indicate it as the problem.

Try the following:
`gethelp.df =tryCatch(htmlTreeParse(gethelp.url, useInternalNodes = T), error = function(cond) next)`

Note that the above line will still throw an error, b/c the example code is not in a loop. So I just replaced `next` with `NA`, and it worked fine.

Edit: In response to OP's comment, I suggest trying the following:

```
gethelp.df =tryCatch(htmlTreeParse(gethelp.url, useInternalNodes = T), error = function(cond)"skip")
if(gethelp.df=="skip"){next}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! by the way even though it's in the loop 'next' doesn't seem to work. I don't know why though.. Have you used tryCatch and next together?

Comment: You could try replacing `next` with `"skip"`, then do `if(gethelp.df=="skip"){next}`. Make sense? Because it's probably trying to assign `next` to `gethelp.df` ... so instead of doing that, just assign a key work ("skip") to gethelp.df, then test for the key word in an `if()` statement, and if it's TRUE, then use the `next`.